# Will docker service discovery properly work with a spark standalone cluster and spark-master in replicated mode for zookeeper failover settings?

Tags: apache-spark, docker, pyspark, docker-swarm

Let's say I have a docker stack that looks something like this:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  spark-master:
    image: gettyimages/spark
    networks:
      - sparknet
    environment:
      MASTER: spark://spark-master:7077
      SPARK_CONF_DIR: /conf
    ports:
      - target: 4040
        published: 4040
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
      - target: 6066
        published: 6066
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
      - target: 7077
        published: 7077
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
      - target: 8080
        published: 8080
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    volumes:
      - spark-master-conf:/conf
      - spark-data:/tmp/data
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.sparkrole == master
    command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master


  spark-worker:
    image: gettyimages/spark
    networks:
      - sparknet
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    environment:
      SPARK_CONF_DIR: /conf
      SPARK_WORKER_CORES: 2
      SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY: 2g
      SPARK_WORKER_PORT: 8881
      SPARK_WORKER_WEBUI_PORT: 8080
      SPARK_MASTER_URL: spark://spark-master:7077
    volumes:
      - spark-worker-conf:/conf
      - spark-data:/tmp/data
    command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://spark-master:7077

networks:
  sparknet:
```

I've tested this and it works fine in this configuration. I can scale up and down the number of workers using `docker service scale` with ease, I can submit jobs, and it all works swimmingly.

Now I've turned my eye towards availability, and I was reading about having [standby masters coordinated with zookeeper](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#standby-masters-with-zookeeper), and it seems straightforward enough, but my only worry comes from the following section of the docs:

> In order to schedule new applications or add Workers to the cluster,
>   they need to know the IP address of the current leader. This can be
>   accomplished by simply passing in a list of Masters where you used to
>   pass in a single one. For example, you might start your SparkContext
>   pointing to spark://host1:port1,host2:port2. This would cause your
>   SparkContext to try registering with both Masters – if host1 goes
>   down, this configuration would still be correct as we’d find the new
>   leader, host2.

Will simply using the built in service discovery docker provides be enough? If I had spark-master scaled up to 3 replicas, and I were to initialize SparkContext with "spark://spark-master:7077", would it resolve to the correct leader node?

Related question:

1. If SparkContext tries to register with `spark://spark-master:7077` and it fails because it got routed to a replicated master node that wasn't the current leader, will it retry?

I think I could get around this in a hack-y way by duplicating spark-master (I.E. Spark-master + spark-master-standy1 ... etc) in my docker-compose file and having SparkContext initialized in my apps with `spark://spark-master:7077,spark-master-standby1:7077...` but this makes easily scaling spark-master with `docker service scale` impossible, this wouldn't be the end of the world, though.

To summarize my actual questions:

1. **Will docker overlay service discovery work properly for standby spark masters**
2. **How does SparkContext handle registering with the leader master? Will it retry on failure? Is this tuneable?**